# Update Eclipse ADT on Windows 8.1

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I cannot update Eclipse ADT. When it tries to read the repositories, I get this error:

> Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/content.xml. 
>   Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/content.xml.
>   Connection reset

It is running on Windows 8.1.

Any help please?

Comment: you are using eclipse juno? try to use the latest which is Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 0):

for eclipse juno :

Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Mylyn for Eclipse Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/juno

The Eclipse Project Updates - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2

Goto to  eclipse  :Click 
    Help -> Install New Software ->

Then click the add button at the right side  ....

```
Add the respective url given above ....
```

your update contents were shown ...

You can update the eclipse ...